# Getting device twin in C Sdk - Azure IoT Hub

Tags: c++, c, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

Is there a way to get the device twin of a device from Azure IoT-Hub, using Azure SDK for C? As far as I know, I am able to get the device twin using the Azure SDK for NodeJS.

In nodejs we do it like.

```
const Client = require('azure-iot-device').Client;
cosnt Protocol = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt').Mqtt;
var client = Client.fromConnectionString(connectionString, Protocol);
function main() {
    client.open(function (err) {
    //If connection is success
    client.getTwin();
    }
});
```

Is there any way to get the twin data for a device and get twinchange notification in Azure SDK for C i.e A callback function when there is a change in twin data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to get the twin data for a device and get twinchange notification in Azure SDK for C i.e A callback function when there is a change in twin data?

Yes, you can refer to example of callback function as per [Get updates on the device side](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-c-c-module-twin-getstarted#get-updates-on-the-device-side):

Try the following code snippet taken from the document:

```
static void deviceTwinCallback(DEVICE_TWIN_UPDATE_STATE update_state, const unsigned char* payLoad, size_t size, void* userContextCallback)
{
    (void)userContextCallback;

    printf("Device Twin update received (state=%s, size=%zu): %s\r\n", 
        MU_ENUM_TO_STRING(DEVICE_TWIN_UPDATE_STATE, update_state), size, payLoad);
}
```

You can also refer to [iothub_devicetwin_sample.c](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/main/iothub_service_client/samples/iothub_devicetwin_sample/iothub_devicetwin_sample.c) and [iothub_device_client.c](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/32942abb994f6855edc2a4dee8afd80735df4151/iothub_client/src/iothub_device_client.c)

Comment: I am trying to upload the code to NodeMCU-ESP32 device. When I add this line   
#include "iothub_devicetwin.h".   I am getting error like iothub_devicetwin.h: No such file or directory


FYI : I am using Arudino IDE

Comment: [device twin for azure-iot-arduino](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-arduino/issues/62),  [AzureIoTHub libraries](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/azureiothub/) and  [unable to find any example to send twin back to cloud](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-arduino/issues/98),

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample on Linux with the SDK for C showing how to deal with Device Twin:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-c/blob/main/sdk/samples/iot/docs/how_to_iot_hub_samples_linux.md#iot-hub-twin-sample